# TextInputLayout remove error border

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, textinputlayout

I Had try

```
        mTextInputLayout.seterror(null);
        mTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
```

how to set error or remove after correction set boarder as default in TextInputLayout Android Application

Answer (score 0):

To set error in `TextInputLayout` , you have to give that

for example,

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/login_userbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/username_text_input_layout" 
                    style="@style/TextLabel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30953551/2826147)

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to validate a EditText field, try adding a TextWatcher to your EditText field.

**For Example**

```
mText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable edt){
      if( mText.getText().length() > 7){
        mText.setError("The input should be grater than 7 characters long");
      }else{
        mText.setError(null);
      }
    }
}
```

As per Android Developer documentation, setError(null) should work to clear errors. For more information [Click Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getError()).