# InputTextLayout setError() method in Android not working

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have designed a customised InputTextLayout which contains a custom Edittext.This custom Edittext extends the "AppCompatEdittext". Also my MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity. But still I am not able to show the error messages using TextInputLayout. Below are my code snippets from various files.

main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/last_name_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/first_name_layout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/grey_button_normal"
            android:hint="Last name"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

            <com.feebite.widgets.StyleableEditText
                android:id="@+id/lastname_edittext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/email_edittext"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/darkish_grey"
                android:textColorHint="@color/darkish_grey"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
mLastNameLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.last_name_layout);
 mLastNameLayout.setHint("Last name");
mLastNameLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
```

Custom theme from styles.xml

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/darkish_grey</item>
        <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/darkish_grey</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/darkish_grey</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/dark_pink</item>
    </style>
```

And the error displayed.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.feebite, PID: 18611
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.feebite/com.feebite.userRegisteration.SignUpActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x45a "res/color/secondary_text_material_light.xml" a=1 r=0x106011e}
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                 at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x45a "res/color/secondary_text_material_light.xml" a=1 r=0x106011e}
                                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:447)
                                                                 at android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray.getColor(XResources.java:1033)
                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:738)
                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:671)
                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:667)
                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:663)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(TextInputLayout.java:380)
                                                                 at com.feebite.userRegisteration.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.java:59)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                 at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
```

Comment: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24: TypedValue`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya how will your suggestion help me?

Comment: I think , Edit text is problem with the above code , Edit text is Not Supported, Check This Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953449/design-android-edittext-to-show-error-message-as-described-by-google

Comment: Use The Default Edit text in Text Input Layout

Comment: @BrahmamYamani previously I did try the default edit text as well but still couldn't get the required results, so tried shifting to AppCompatEdittext.

Comment: @AndroidMech It's Working Fine Placing of Default Edit Text Input Layout ,i'm not getting any error  and I am using 23 API Level,i think it's api level problem Update 23 Api Level In Gradle File It's Workin Fine

Answer (score 33):

Try to set the following attributes too:

```
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/Your color</item>
<item name="android:textColorLink">@color/Your color</item>
```

Comment: This helped me with exactly the same issue.

Comment: this fixed my issue

Comment: helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Had exactly the same problem and none of the answers solved.
What really worked was removing this: `parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat"`

Answer (score 0):

There are different attributes you could be using for your TextInputLayout, as

- `app:errorEnabled`: To toggle error visibility and use an empty string when no error should be shown. We could also use setError(null).
- `app:errorTextAppearance`: Text appearance for the error text. We could use something like @style/TextInputLayout.ErrorText.
- `app:hintTextAppearance`: Text appearance for the hint text. We could use something like @style/TextInputLayout.HintText.

where:

```
<style name="TextInputLayout"/>

<style name="TextInputLayout.ErrorText">
  <item name="textColorError">#FFD50000</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputLayout.HintText">
  <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_tiny_size</item>
</style>
```

The one you are looking for is `app:errorTextAppearance`. You could also use `android:theme` to make the container's small EditText (hint) inherit your application theme configuration.