# how to use this element of edittext in android

Tags: android, apk, android-textinputedittext

[image]

when input is not valid, instead of toast or sth else this kind of new thing appears to warn the user . Does anyone know how I can use it in my own app  ?
Image is attached . Tnx in advance .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Design Android EditText to show error message as described by google](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953449/design-android-edittext-to-show-error-message-as-described-by-google)

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30953551/3894781)

Answer (score 0):

That pop up is an error pop up which appears when error is set.

```
TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.text_input_layout);
til.setError("Your error");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `myEditText.setError("insert error message here")`
One gotcha is that if`myEditText` is not the one that is currently focused you will not see the error message itself, just the exclamation mark like in the below example.
[image]

To avoid this you should always call `myEditText.requestFocus()` before calling `setError`

Lastly, to clear the error just call `myEditText.setError(null)`