# Can you add a textview or something similar as a child to a textinputlayout?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have an application that uses a lot of textinputlayouts because I like the style they create

on one screen I am showing info on one object and I want it too look like the data the user entered with the textinputedittexts , small caption above and the data below

right now I have a textinputlayout with a disabled textinputedittext below

is there a way to just have a textview under the textinputlayout that will be shown in the same style?

thanks in advance for any help you can provide

edit:

as a side note here's what I am currently using to disable the edittext fully

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        tools:text="This is where the name goes"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

what I am trying to avoid is not use clickable and inputtype etc etc in EVERY view that I'm trying to create, and instead use a single view

so other than creating a custom edittext (like NeverEnabledEditText) that starts unclickabke in every way, or add all those attributes to my xml, is there a way to do the above?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953449/design-android-edittext-to-show-error-message-as-described-by-google

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Design Android EditText to show error message as described by google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953449/design-android-edittext-to-show-error-message-as-described-by-google)

Comment: no , what I want is to NOT use an eddittext as a child, I want to use a completely uneditable view (like textview) as a child

Comment: Whats the use of keeping textview in textinputlayout ?

Comment: to make it look similar to the textinputlayout with edittext, when the textview has data it shows a small caption and the data beneath, when there is no data it shows the caption in place of the textview

Comment: did you ever find a solution? i want to do the same (except keep it clickable)

Comment: no after switching to kotlin I just created an extension function that does what I want and I call it whenever I want to disable the view  ,something like `fun TextInputEditText.setEnabled(enabled:Boolean) { this.isClickable = enabled; this.focusable = enabled; }`,  on a recent project that only had non editable edittexts I created two textviews one which was styled after textinputlayout's hint style and below it my normal textview (I dug up inside the material design code and found the styles)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/date_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Date"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:paddingVertical="12dp"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:text="00/00/0000" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Although a TextInputEditText, now you have it acting like a textview because you can't edit it but can set text to it. You're welcome !