# How to Hide error message prompt?

Tags: android, android-edittext, navigation-drawer, android-textinputedittext, error-messaging

I need to display an error message in `edittext` view when filed is empty or invalid.

Issue is when any `edittext` has error message prompt at that time if user open navigation drawer error message appear over the drawer.

I want navigation drawer always open over the error message. So when drawer close, user always have error message for invalid `editext`.

Note: This issue is not observed in `Samsung` device(`Android 7.0`)
Observed in `Moto` and `lenovo` devices.

[image]

Images with error message over drawer.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_eextra_wide"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_eextra_wide">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            style="@style/Text.Medium"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text="@string/title_add_care_recipient"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_16pt"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sub_title"
            style="@style/Text.Medium"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:text="@string/sub_title_add_care_recipient"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_14pt"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/MaterialDesignTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_first_name"
                style="@style/EditText.Medium.Mandatory"
                android:hint="@string/hint_first_name"
                android:maxLength="50"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/MaterialDesignTextInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_last_name"
                style="@style/EditText.Medium.Mandatory"
                android:hint="@string/hint_last_name"
                android:maxLength="50"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_next"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding"
                android:background="@color/orange"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:text="@string/text_save"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: share your layout xml

Comment: It's good practice to set error on `TextInputLayout` rather then `EditText`, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953449/design-android-edittext-to-show-error-message-as-described-by-google)

Comment: add `editText.clearFocus();` in `onDrawerOpen` method

Answer (score 4):

When your **drawer open**  clear Focus form `EditText`  using

```
editText.clearFocus();
```

**OR**

You have `TextInputLayout` so try to set Error on `TextInputLayout` .

**And it's better to set error on `TextInputLayout`**

```
textInputLayout.setError("Error message");
textInputLayout.setError(null);//for remove error
textInputLayout.setErrorEnable(false); //for remove error
```

Comment: This can be last option to handled this issue. But I have 4 tabs at bottom and all contains 3-4 edittext fields.

Comment: yaa but i have seen your code xml you will use android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout so its batter to use TextInputLayout.setError() method