# setTextAppearance()

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an app and want to show error if someone didn't fill-up the form correctly. Can I change the style of each component in Android Studio using java to highlight the component.

What I've done so far is this:

**1.** in styles.xml file, I did declare a new style name errorstyle as following:

```
<style name="errorstyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#f45c42</item>
</style>
```

**2.** secondly in java file I did try to use following code.

```
selectedDate.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.errorstyle);
```

And it gives me an error message in java file:

> cannot resolve symbol 'errorstyle'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Design Android EditText to show error message as described by google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953449/design-android-edittext-to-show-error-message-as-described-by-google)

Answer (score 0):

> cannot resolve symbol 'errorstyle'

```
<style name="errorstyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Style **`errorstyle`** in your style section, So don't call **`android.R.`** Use **`R.style`** instead.

**Do**

```
selectedDate.setTextAppearance(R.style.errorstyle);
```

**FYI**

> [**`setTextAppearance(Context context, int resId)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance(android.content.Context,%20int))
>
> This method was
>   deprecated in API level 23.

Use [**`setTextAppearance(int)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance(int)) instead.

Comment: still it shows the error 'cannot resolve symbol 'errorstyle''

Comment: @RajindPamoda do `selectedDate.setTextAppearance(R.style.errorstyle);  `

Comment: @RajindPamoda Solved this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `R.style.errorstyle` instead of `android.R.style.errorstyle`. Resources in `android.R.*` are coming from Android, resources created by you is in `R.*`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `R.style.errorstyle` instead of `R.android.style.errorstyle`. Sometimes it takes a while for Android Studio to recognize a style that you may have override. 
Try rebuilding the project or invalidate cache and restart android studio.