# how to show an error for EditTextPreference

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, sharedpreferences

**I am trying to show the user an error when they enter a value for an EditTextPreference incorrectly.**

[image: google material design guidelines]

Currently I have a onPreferenceChangeListener which returns true or false:

```
editTextPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                if (newValue.toString().length() < 1 || Integer.parseInt(newValue.toString()) < 1) {
                    return false;
                } else {

                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
```

I found this question [Design Android EditText to show error message as described by google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953449/design-android-edittext-to-show-error-message-as-described-by-google), but it is for a EditText not an EditTextPreference. Now I am trying to find a similar solution that I can use for EditTextPreference.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: The rest of my code would be the default Settings Activity. Do you need to see any specifics? Thanks