# Add caracter count and error message on edittext landscape layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Is there a way to have a custom view when i have the focus in a editText in landscape[image]

i would like to add the caracter count, error message while the user is in this view.

I Look at Input Method Engine put it seem to be only for the keyboard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Design Android EditText to show error message as described by google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953449/design-android-edittext-to-show-error-message-as-described-by-google)

Comment: No i already am using TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText. I want to be able to see the number of caract when the user is in landscape and the TextInputEditText is in full screen. I would also like to keep seeing the title and the error if there's one. While i'm in "fullscreen mode"